# Work with different version ROS (Robot operating system)

Tags: ros, ros2

Is there a way to publish using ROS1 based ros version in one machine and subscribe to these same topics from another machine that only use ROS2 versions like humble.

Clarification
Machine 1
Version1: ROS1
Distro: Naotic
Publisher Node: Publisher1
Topic: /sampletopic

Machine 2
Version2: ROS2
Distro: Humble
Subscriber Node: Subscriber1
Subscribing to Topic: /sampletopic

It is common to export ros_core_master among ROS1 distros. Couldn't get a way to cross-communicate with ROS1 and ROS2 based publishers and subscribers? It is mainly due to difference in Architecture but there must be some possibility.
Thank you in advance for the insights.

Answer (score 2):

It isn’t possible to do, easily, within ROS natively. However a package for this already exists, [The ROS1 Bridge.](https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge)

Answer (score 1):

1. On Ubuntu 20.04 (or older) between ROS1 Noetic and ROS2 Foxy / Glactic use the [Ros1 bridge](https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge). And simply install with apt `sudo apt install ros-foxy-ros1-bridge`
2. On Ubuntu 22.04 there is no new ROS1 version anymore. To communicate with ROS2 Humle you need to install ROS2 from source. Here is a guide: https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/How-To-Guides/Using-ros1_bridge-Jammy-upstream.html